# Complexity of blind sort?

Tags: cc.complexity-theory, terminology, sorting

We all know that the minimal complexity of a comparison-based sorting algorithm is $\Omega(n \log n)$ comparisons. I'm trying to do a *blind* sort, i.e. given a number $n$ output a circuit (with boolean, arithmetic and "comparison" gates) that sorts a list of $n$ items.

Precomputing all ${n \choose 2}$ comparisons and then doing arithmetic on the resulting bits gets me an $\Theta(n^3)$ algorithm, however by some crazy "pointer arithmetic" I think I can get a $\Theta(n^2)$ version.

Is there a known lower bound for comparison-based sorting circuits along similar lines to the $n \log n$ one for comparison-based sorting algorithm? Might it even be possible to blind sort in $n \log n$ time?

Comment: What's your background? did you search around it? e.g [bionic sorter](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bitonic_sorter) gives a good network with size $O(n\cdot {\log^2 n})$, and time for creating corresponding network is at most as size of the network.

Comment: My background is in cryptography and I'm looking at sorting secret-shared data, which gives some rather unusual constraints on the relative cost of operations. I'm wondering whether I have hit an edge case where `n^2` is a lower bound or whether it can't be brought down to the usual `n log n` after all - just checking to see if there's any situations where a higher bound such as `n^2` is already known.

Comment: Actually by background I mean, because here people are trying to ask [research level](http://cstheory.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) questions, so when you provide just a very naive approach means there is not much research behind the question, may be some other sites is better suited for this.

Comment: I think the technical term for what you call blind sorting is _oblivious "[sorting network](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sorting_network)"_.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

[Goodrich's "Randomized Shellsort: A Simple Oblivious Sorting Algorithm"](http://www.siam.org/proceedings/soda/2010/SODA10_101_goodrichm.pdf) has a discussion of data-oblivious sorting. [Sorting networks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sorting_network) are data-oblivious, but impractical in general, as I understand it.

Comment: I think bitonic sort is not as impractical, but it's $O(n\log^2 n)$. THe AKS sorting network is definitely impractical.